# scanf() function is not holding the screen for user to enter data

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

I have used `scanf()` to hold the screen and take input from user in a multi threaded client side socket program.
`scanf()` is not holding the screen here and user is not able to enter data.
The code of thread function is is:

```
void *send_data(void *num)
{
     int *sock_s=(int *) num;
     int sock=*sock_s;
     char msg[50];
     printf("Enter data:");


     while(1) {
          scanf("%s",msg);
          if(strcmp(msg,"exit")==0)
          {
               break;
          }
          send(sock_s,msg,sizeof(msg),0);
     }
     send(sock,msg,sizeof(msg),0);
}
```

and the code create tthis thread is:

```
     status_s=pthread_create(&thread_s,NULL,send_data,(void *)&sock);
            if(status_s==0)
                    printf("sending");
```

Comment: what does the msg contain after scanf returns ?

Comment: Please put some minimum effort into fixing the messy indention before posting to this site.

Comment: what do you mean by 'holding the screen' ? I can see you want to interact with an user, why don't you use read() instead. `n = read(STDIN_FILENO, &msg[0], 49); msg[n]  = '\0';` this may not solve your problem, but you'll no longer use those functions.

Comment: `send(sock_s,msg,sizeof(msg),0);` is wrong, `send`'s first argument is an `int`. You meant `sock` there.

Comment: @DanielFischer Nicely spotted, you should post that as an answer, it might just be the bug that the OP is looking for. It is definitely a bug anyhow.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer I have made the changes regarding socket but the problem persistes...

Answer (score 2):

- You leave trailing line feed characters in stdin. This question is such a FAQ, it gets asked at least 5 timer per day. Search for scanf on this site... Solution: `scanf(" %s", msg);` or similar.
- You can't use plain `scanf` and similar library functions from inside a thread, they are not thread-safe.
- The way you use it, `scanf` is vulnerable and will get buffer overruns.

Comment: He _is_ using scanf("%s"), isn't he? So this doesn't seem to be the usual fgets-reads-an-old-newline problem.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy Please note the space in the format string. `%s`alone doesn't fix the trailing line feed.

Comment: The `%s` conversion skips initial whitespace. Only `%c`, `%[` and `%n` conversions don't.

Comment: @Lundin: As Daniel Fischer wrote, "%s" and " %s" will act the same here, since "%s" already skips initial whitespace. If the OP's problem is that the program doesn't stop and wait for input, that doesn't seem to be caused by the usual trailing line feed FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

The buffer might have a "\r" or "\n" in it. we need to flush the input buffer in order to remove it.

use [fflush](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush)(stdin) function to flush the buffer.

```
fflush(stdin)  
scanf("%s", msg );
```

Edit: Did you tried to use fgets instead of scanf ?

```
fgets(msg);
```

Comment: No, fflush(stdin)  gives undefined behavior according to the C standard.

Answer (score -1):

try this and see whether it works

```
     printf("Enter data:");
      scanf("\n%s",msg);

while(strcmp(msg,"exit")!=0)
{
   send(sock_s,msg,sizeof(msg),0);
        scanf("\n%s",msg);


}
```

i think there might be some problem with the while loop

Comment: @Lundin some programs work in weird ways when while(1)..:).just a guess